# Question mark is not visible

Tags: sql

```
select case when 'A​B' = 'A?B' then 1 else 0 end
```

Result:1

Why is the question mark in the first string not visible？

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Did you mean `select case when [A​B] = 'A?B' then 1 else 0 end` (MSSQL) or `select case when \`A​B\` = 'A?B' then 1 else 0 end` (MySQL)?

Comment: Even in oracle 10g, `select case when 'A​B' = 'A?B' then 1 else 0 end from dual` evaluates to **1**

Comment: There is a hidden character.

Comment: What you are asking is not at all clear.

Comment: When I *copy* this line and execute in SqlServer, I get the same result (1). When I edit that 'AB' (including quotes) into 'AB' again, I get 0 as expected. So what is in the original `'AB'`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I just tested it, it showed me 1

Comment: There is a hidden ASCII 63 charachter: `SELECT LEN('A​B')
SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING('A​B', 2, 1))`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i copied the select statement from the question, and pasted it to the query window that i have, i noticed in the executed query that it is A?B = A?B, so i guess there is a hidden ? character in the left hand side

Comment: This is producing correct result when used in SQLSERVER 2008,but not in SQLSERVER2012

Comment: There is a hidden character in 'A​B'.The hidden character of ASCII is 63.Why is this character hidden away？

Answer (score 4):

That first `'AB'` is really (A) (zero width space) (B).

For SqlServer a quoted string without an N prefix is treated as a single-byte-per-character string. Apparently the "non ascii" zero width space is translated into a question mark before comparing.

Adding the "N-prefix" gives the expected result (0):

```
select case when N'A​B' = N'AB' then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Can that be somehow officially confirmed, that invalid or zero-width characters are converted to `?` internally?

Comment: Is this use case confirmed or documented somewhere?

Comment: In .Net, when you use [ASCIIEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx), any non-ASCII characters are translated into question marks (see remarks there). This behavior of SqlServer may be similar (at least it looks like that).

Comment: Yes, it rather seems to be the default behavior of some components used by SQL Server (Oracle, MySQL) than something by design in SQL Server. @Grace I find this answer quite acceptable...

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your sql statement, don't copy and past it, it has a hidden ? character

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with data entry employees, they copy/paste the data instead of writing it down ( it is data of max 25 characters)

Comment: you can edit your data before saving by omitting undesired characters programmatically, specially if you know what they usually are

Comment: I have actually, but since '?' is a hidden character,it always fools the regex and the controllers and it gets written into database

Comment: i dont think it is hidden, you need to know the ascii code that forms these special characters, see [Vojtěch Dohnal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629661/question-mark-is-not-visible/34630194#34630194)  for this question

Comment: I see, the character actually appears when the data has been sent with some kind of formatting (italic,bold or different color than black)

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is encoded using this three bytes `E2 80 8B`, but how? - it beats hell out of me, but it is indeed so. Perhaps the SQL replaces internaly this invalid characters with one single `?`. 
When I open the text in PSPad and switch to HEX view and back, I get the normal visible `?` char too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
select case when ('A​B' = 'A?B' AND LEN('A​B') = LEN('A?​B')) then 1 else 0 end
```